# If this is true, then do this... explanation?

Tags: php

The method:

```
    public function checkName($name)
    {
        $this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :name");
        $this->check->execute(array(":name" => $name));

        if ($this->check->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This code apparently doesn't work:

```
if (!$user->checkName('Jony'))
{
 echo '1';
}
```

Even if I have Jony in the database, it echoing '1'.

This code works:

```
if ($user->checkName('Jony') != true) 
{
    echo '1';
}
```

This doesn't echo '1', but echoing 1 if I dont include jony, and its not in the database.

**I thought you can just do if (true) then..., do you actually have to include if != true or if == true?**

Comment: Your checkName routine never returns false, so how could !checkName() ever be true? You're probably falling off the end of the routine and getting undefined in the caller...  which I think is falsy, but explicitly returning false should be better.

Comment: You don't return false from your function, which may not be necessary but it helps.

Comment: I only check if it's true, why do I need to return false aswell?

Comment: Of course you have to.

Comment: @JonyKale: Because otherwise it's undefined, which causes unexpected behaviors...

Comment: However, your code is full of errors, even the method used to check for existence of record(s)..

Comment: It does indeed return `NULL` per default, which would work with the plain boolean `if` test. The actual glaring bug here is the naming of you function. `checkBlabla` does not say anything about what it checks. It would better be called `userNameExists()`.

Comment: youeither need to return false or cast as a bool so !(bool)checkName

Comment: Technically, `!null` returns `true`. At least on PHP 5.4.4 it does.

Comment: I did not know that basically, thanks. But why the -2?

Comment: am i the only one that sees he is defining a method in a class and calls it as a regular function ?

Comment: @Twisted1919 It's just an example.

Comment: @JonyKale - it's a good idea to use your real code, otherwise you are confusing people.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank's I edited it.

Comment: in one example you use "Jony" and then you use "jony" (lowercased) just to help out finding your error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having you updated your question, I can see the problem.
This statement is totally wrong:

```
if ($user->!checkName('Jony'))
```

You should test the value in this way:

```
if (!$user->checkName('Jony'))
```

However, if you pasted it right, your code should not work at all because it causes a Parsing error as you can see here: http://ideone.com/CPfkNi

Comment: +1 The edit made all the difference... I couldn't reproduce the issue even in test code.

Comment: @JonyKale: No worries, happens to the best of us - as long as it's a lesson learned, that's what really matters ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can simplify your function a bit by returning the result of your comparison.

```
public function checkName($name)
{
    $this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :name");
    $this->check->execute(array(":name" => $name));

    return $this->check->rowCount() > 0;
}
```

You also need to move the not operator.

```
!$user->checkName('Jony')
```